# SSRS auto-fit gauges in panel

Tags: reporting-services, indicator, gauge

Indicator automatically extends when the row in the table will be more than one line of text. Here is an example how it looks like:

[image: screen]

What to do to not change its size?
There is an option such "Auto-fit all gauges in panel" in Indicator properties. But I don't understand how it works and what should I do to change it in right way.

Any tips? ;)

Comment: have you tried changing the `canGrow` property on the row to false? or is there other text that isn't visible in the screenshot forcing the rows to be different sizes?

Comment: I can't do this (change the canGrow property) because in my row there are Gauge Panels (I think that this is the reason).    
And yes, there is the other text: the column with names of products. Another screenshot: http://imgur.com/8vPHBO1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put a rectangle within your table cell, and put the indicator within that.. This should ensure that the indicator size stays uniform.

Also remember to remove the rectangle borders where required.

Comment: Ok, their size doesn't change, but now I have sth like this ;x 
http://imgur.com/5k9sGAI

Comment: You should remove rectangle border.. to center the indicator you could try adding another two empty rectangles to the table cell, one above and one below.

Comment: I think the cell is to small to put more than one rectangle. When I remove rectangle border and when even change its size to smaller, border of cell in tablix will disappear too. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Ok, I got it ;) I set rectangle border style on Bottom --> Solid. Thanks!